# How to add generic object to list in java?

Tags: java, generics, collections

How to add a generic object to list in java?

Currently, I have two classes doing the same function and would like to integrate them together

```
public class MyClass1 {
    private List<Object1> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addList(Object1 o) {
        myList.add(o);
    }
} 

public class MyClass2 {
    private List<Object2> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addList(Object2 o) {
        myList.add(o);
}
}
```

something like

```java
public class MyClass {
    private List<Object> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addList(Object o) {
        myList.add(o);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could make your own class generic:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
    private List<T> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addList(T o) {
        myList.add(o);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make both classes `Object1` and `Object2` implement the same interface 'ObjInterface'

```
public class MyClass {
    private List<ObjInterface> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addList(ObjInterface o) {
        myList.add(o);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the class to contain only Object1 or only Object2 and never anything else, you can combine the other two answers:

```
interface ObjInterface {
    // may be empty
}

public class MyClass<T extends ObjInterface> {
    private List<T> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addList(T o) {
        myList.add(o);
    }
}

MyClass<Object1> object1only = new MyClass<>();
MyClass<Object2> object2only = new MyClass<>();
```

and add `implements ObjInterface` to the definitions of Object1 and Object2.

If you add methods common to both classes to `ObjInterface`, you can call those methods on the `T` objects in `MyClass`, since they're guaranteed to be a subclass of `ObjInterface`.